# How to install GHC in Appveyor and put GHC in path?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, appveyor

I'm trying to install GHC on windows with the following script (and put ghc in path), but it fails when I try to run `ghci --version`. I think there is something wrong with the script.

```
install:
  - ps: Invoke-WebRequest "https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar.xz" -OutFile "ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar.xz"
  - 7z x ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar.xz
  - ps: $env:path += "C:\projects\haskell-interactive-mode\ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar\ghc-8.0.2\bin"
  - ps: ghci --version
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your command on local Windows machine and I see that `7z x ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar.xz` results in `ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar` **file**, not **folder**. If you unzip it further with `7z x ghc-8.0.2-i386-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar`, it unzips into real **folder** named `ghc-8.0.2` with `bin` subfolder and `ghci.exe` file.

However I think that simpler it would be use [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ghc/8.0.2.2). This works for me well:

```
  - choco install ghc
  - refreshenv
  - ghci --version
```